# What are recommended ways to refactor the internal representation of a class?

Tags: unit-testing, refactoring

Say I have a class which stores some data in a private variable 'data', e.g. an array. There are different methods of this class using the data variable and different unit tests testing these methods. Now for some reason you want to change the container type of data (e.g. a map instead of an array), which needs to be handled in a slightly different way. If one simply changes the type of data from array to map all the code in the methods gets broken and one would have to change them all before any unit tests can be run again. This usually is not what one wants. So what is the recommended way to do this iteratively without breaking all the code at once ?

Comment: Err, yes, this is exactly what one wants: you apply changes until the code compiles again, you run the tests, and if they still pass, then you haven't broken the expected behavior of the class while doing all those changes. You can comment out some method bodies and make tests pass one by one if you want. But then it's a good thing that the tests testing the commented out method bodies fail, isn't it?

Comment: "...all the code in the methods gets broken and one would have to change them all..." if your classes are sane and do only one thing this should not be a problem. If you classes are doing too much you should fix that first.

Comment: Ok I just thought it would be nicer to 'always' have the code to compile and check one test after the other. Obviously if I first break the code and then change the code until it compiles again (this I wanted to rather do in smaller pieces) I can check the tests and if they succeed everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests typically test the outer functionality of a class.

Therefore a refactor of a classes "internals" should not break any tests. 
(this is one of the benefits of testing. ).

Many IDE's will allow you to do a automated refactor of internals in one hit. but you did not specify the language or IDE which you are using.

If your class is so large that a change to a data-type creates "hours" of work then you should probably consider breaking your class into smaller bits of functionality prior to a refactor of the data type.

Alternatively you could hand refactor in chunks and attempt to keep the class stable and 'commenting out' the array definition temporarily to help tell you where you need to focus.

Comment: The problem is not that anything breaks the tests, but the code won't compile after changing the internals. Automated refactoring of a std::map into a std::vector using c++ and eclipse cdt ?

Comment: Well in that case you have to refactor to the point where the code will compile again, if you tag your question with your language and ide you may be able to get a more specific answer .